# Angular - resolver and component not sharing injected service?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I have a table to display some products in my products list component. There is a moderate amount of data, so I've added in a resolver to not land the user on the page until the data is loaded. Right now, my resolver injects my products service, which has its own methods to load the data from my backend and save the products in an array inside the service. So my resolver injects this service, calls the load products function to prefetch the data and then the component loads.

The question is now, what's the best way to re-use the data in the products list component? For some reason, if I inject the same service into the products list component, I can see that the products are not loaded, so I'm not sure if my resolver and component are injecting the same singleton of my service.

If I simply use the resolver to pass along the products that it got from the service itself, then my component can get access to these, but when it comes to making updates to them, it won't be writing changes to my products list service, which is needed elsewhere for other components.

What's the best structure/approach to this kind of setup. I'm sure it can't be that uncommon?

Comment: you are providing your service in providers of your module right ?

Comment: yes, it's provided in both my products list module and the module (app module) that loads my resolver

Comment: In this case you should create a shareModule which will be imported by both modules (product list and app). By this only one instance of service will be created whereas now two instances are being created

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems to be working now. Just a question of what’s good practice now. Since my resolver only purpose is to run the methods in my service, it doesn’t need to return these to the component because it injects the service as well. So is this good practice? Should I not return anything from the resolver?

Comment: Separation of concern as you are using is a good practice. Since your resolver only responsibility should be to get that required data and save it to own data object which your routed component could use on loading. After that Component will be using the same service instance but for modification purpose. That's how you are separating the use of service.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at Angular documentation there is stated as follows "Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a **shared module**. A lazy-loaded NgModule that imports that shared module makes its own copy of the service.."

So an service you want to have as an singleton should be provided in the Core module which you import once when the app starts and never import anywhere else.

Here is the link to the [detailed explanation of the Core module.](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#the-core-module)

Have a great day :)

Comment: Thanks for the supporting documentation. Seems to be working well now, and I’m getting a better understanding of the modules.

Answer (score 0):

you solve this issue in two steps (*without creating a new shared module*):

1. remove your service from the product list module if it exists in the providers' array.
2. add injectable decorator with the 'root' option like this `@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root'})` above the service class declaration.

**note**

with the 'root' option, now your service in *singleton in the whole app*, you'll get the benefit of angular's ***tree-shaking*** feature that removes the unused service instances.