# Object returned by a service is empty during routing

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service in the application I develop which takes in items I click on and stores them in a state, merging new items in as I click on them. I can access this stored state by calling a function which returns an Observable (lets call it `getItems`).

I also have a method which navigates to a different part of the application, using the @angular/router package, and then the navigate method - `this.router.navigate(path);`. It's important that the items above which are stored in the service are then available to the application in the new route - which they are. However, I am now attempting to implement a feature where it looks at the items while/before navigating to the route, as a new feature of the application may require an extra HTTP request be made based on the items present in the store. The problem is, when I do this (in a Resolve method), the service returns an empty object. When the navigation has finished and I make another call to the service, it returns the correct items. So why is the service briefly returning an empty object in the resolve method? Here is an example (heavily simplified) of my code:

```
export const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExampleComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/child', loadChildren: './child-component/child-component.module#ChildComponentModule', resolve: {
        objSummary: ComponentResolverService
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So when I add items to the store (by clicking on them), I'm at `/`. Then, I click on a link/button which takes me to `/child`. Next is is the `ComponentResolverService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentResolverService implements Resolve<ObjectType> {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private itemStoreService: ItemStoreService) {}

  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<ObjectType> {
    // this method returns the result of an HTTP call. In that HTTP call, I need to get the items which have previously been stored
    let request: Observable<ObjectType>;
    this.itemStoreService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items); // returned as empty object {}
      request = this.http.post<ObjectType>(apiUrl, items);
    });
    return request;
  }
}
```

If I make a request to `itemStoreService.getItems()` in the ChildComponent, it returns an object with the items I had previously added to the store. It's just in the Resolver it returns empty.

Finally, the `ItemStoreService`:

```
interface Item {
  attribute1: string;
  attribute2: string;
}

interface Store<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

export class ItemStoreService {

  private items: BehaviorSubject<Store<Item>> = new BehaviorSubject<Store<Item>>();
  private itemData: Store<Item>;

  public getItems(): Observable<Store<Item>> {
    return this.items.map((x: Store<Item) => _.cloneDeep(x));
  }

  public addItem(itemName: string, item: Item): void {
    this.itemData[itemName] = item;
    this.items.next(this.itemData);
  }

}
```

the `addItem` method is called when in the main component (rendered at '/') when an item is clicked on. I haven't included this code as it's not the problem, but included the method for completeness.

So basically: `getItems()` returns an Observable with the correct items everywhere but the Resolver service, where it returns an empty object, and I need it returning the items in the resolver service so that I can make a HTTP request to the API the application is developed on.

EDIT: a little more information, using the Chrome debugger: I added a breakpoint where the link is clicked and the router is engaged: (`return this.router.navigate(path);`). Here, in the Chrome debugger scope panel, the `itemStoreService` is in scope and the value of the BehaviorSubject variable contains the items stored. So this is fine. However, I added a breakpoint to the resolver service, and found the itemStoreService in scope; the value of the `items` here is `{}`. So somewhere between the initial route activation and the resolving of the route, the data is lost, and then found again when the child component has been rendered. I will continue to add more breakpoints and check, hopefully this will enable me to find the point where it's lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to import any service which should remain the same throughout the application in the core/root app.module.ts file. I was importing ItemStoreService seperately in multiple `NgModule` declarations, which meant it was being injected seperately. Due to this, in some places the `items` variable was being re-initialised as an empty object; one of these places was in my routing from component to component (but was defined the same in each component).

For answer completeness, the code above can remain exactly the same, I just had to ensure in app.module.ts I was importing the ItemStoreService:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [
   ItemStoreService,
   ...
  ]
});
```

and then I had to ensure the ItemStoreService was not being imported in any other modules.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568592/angular-resolver-and-component-not-sharing-injected-service) for providing me with the initial solution.